# How to enumerate tables in SQL Server database and perform DML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How is a database enumerated for its tables in a way that you can perform DML on them? I've already accomplished retrieving table names from a single statement:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM MyDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

Most of my tables have a special field with the same name, and I want to update them all to the same value through table enumeration. The structure of the database is in a way that I cannot use the referential integrity for update propagation and this is a special case for me to update manually. I'm not sure how to loop through and update the common field within them, and specified a try-catch block for the tables that do not have the SpecialField. as like:

```
declare @i int =0;
While(@i < MyDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.length)
begin
   begin try
     Update MyDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES[i] set SpecialField= SomeValue;
   end try
   begin catch end catch
   set @i=@i+1;
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use MyDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and put a WHERE clause on the column name. So that way you do not need the try, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use dynamic SQL, i.e. construct the `UPDATE` statement in a string (VarChar) and use the `EXEC` command to execute the command. As I don't know the specific RDBMS you're using, I cannot give you an example. But basically, it would look similar to this:

```
declare @cmd VarChar(80)
declare @i int =0;
While(@i < MyDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.length)
begin
   begin try
     set @cmd='Update '+MyDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES[i];
     set @cmd=@cmd +' set SpecialField= '+cast(SomeValue as VarChar);
     exec (@cmd)
   end try
   begin catch end catch
   set @i=@i+1;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `sp_MSforeachtable`, but I admit that it does not look much simpler.
It does, however, directly look for tables that contain that correct column.
The table name is accessible through `?` within the statement, but in the format `'[dbo].[tablename]'`.

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable  '
    IF ''?'' IN (
        SELECT ''['' + TC.TABLE_SCHEMA + ''].['' + TC.TABLE_NAME + '']''
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS TC
        WHERE TC.COLUMN_NAME = ''SpecialField''
        )
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE sp_executesql N''UPDATE ? SET [SpecialField] = NULL'';
        PRINT ''? done'';
    END
    ELSE 
        PRINT ''? skipped'';
';
```

Answer (score 1):

I finalized it this way, so others can use my code:

```
DECLARE @DBTables TABLE (
    ID int,
    Name varchar(200)
);

with DBTables as
(
    SELECT Row_Number() over(order by TABLE_NAME) as ID,TABLE_NAME as Name FROM  
                                            PTBilling.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
)
insert into @DBTables (ID,Name) select ID,Name from DBTables;

declare @cmd varchar(1000);
declare @OldID int =10714;
declare @NewID int=200;
declare @ID int =1;
declare @tableMaxID int=(select max(ID) from @DBTables);
While(@ID < @tableMaxID)
begin
   begin try
     set @cmd='Update '+ (select top 1 Name from @DBTables where ID=@ID);
     set @cmd= @cmd +' set ID= '+ cast(@NewID as varchar)+ 
                   ' where ID=' + cast(@OldID as varchar);
     exec (@cmd)
   end try
   begin catch end catch
   set @ID = @ID+1;
end
```